# Load-balancing Database Connection Pool

Tags: oracle, tomcat

What database connection pool could be used to load-balance connections from a Tomcat web container to one of several Oracle database servers without using RAC clustering?

Comment: What does load balancing mean, in this context?

Comment: @skaffman: I mean to have a connection pool that consists of connections to various cloned databases hosted on different Oracle servers so that connection requests are served by different databases according to some round-robin like algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming these are read-only databases or you're not concerned connections will get different data.  If you want the data to be the same, you can use streams replication which is doesn't require RAC.

The connection load balancing and failover happens in the listener.  There's a lot of flexibility in how this works and this should get you started:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/advcfg.htm#sthref858

The first part shows a simple client based load balance which is essentially picking a connection at random.  Farther down it shows how to load balance based on actual server load.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [DRCP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc002.htm) if using 11g

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but, from my initial reading, this appears to be for connecting multiple clients to a single database server.  I'm considering the case of a single client connecting to multiple servers.